# How to add a new target organization for outbound change set?

Tags: deployment, sandbox

Is it possible to change or add target organization on salesforce sandbox?

Comment: Prasad, do you want to add more possible sandboxes to deploy to, or are you wondering whether it's possible to add the destination of a change set once it's uploaded ?  Putting more effort in a question and adding sufficient detail helps us help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order for change sets to be sent from one organization to another, a deployment connection is required between the organizations. Check the below link for more information.

[Deployment Connections](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets_about_connection.htm&language=en_US)

Answer (score 1):

After you uploaded the change set to a target organization, you can't change it again and only upload it again to that organization. You could however clone the change set, save it (under the same or a different name) and then upload it to another target organization.

Comment: Just realized that I answered the question in the title, while your description asks another question. I think the answer Tonino Tripodo gave, is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

1. go to your target instance , then **Setup** , which is located @ https://SFDC.InstaceDomainName/lightning/setup/SetupOneHome/home
2. Left hand search box , key in "**Deployment Settings**"
3. you will see list of connection there tell the relationship between instance.
4. Click "**edit**" , then check "Allow Inbound Changes" to accept upload
5. Now this target instance name will automatically populated on source instance "**Outbound Change Sets**" screen